# ffmpeg encode H.264 with Nvidia hardware encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, nvidia

I have a GTX 660 with nvidias fancy hardware H.264 encoder, I also have a bunch of video files I would like to encode into H.264. Is it possible to tell ffmpeg to use my hardware H.264 encoder instead of my CPU for encoding video?

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in solution with FFmpeg.

But it's possible if you code using the NVIDIA SDK. I did it by myself. But the quality of the NVIDIA H.264 HE is terrible compared to libx264. I didn't find anyone else that got satisfied with the results... :-(

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, ffmpeg 2.6 now includes support (from 
http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=RELEASE_NOTES;hb=release/2.6):

```
A lot of people will probably be happy to hear that we now 
have support for NVENC — the Nvidia Video Encoder interface for 
H.264 encoding — thanks to Timo Rothenpieler, with some little 
help from NVIDIA and Philip Langdale.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure ffmpeg with -enable-nvenc key and use -vcodec nvenc 
 Please read [this documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/ffmpeg/1511-patch/FFMPEG-with-NVIDIA-Acceleration-on-Ubuntu_UG_v01.pdf) for more information.